# App Settings change: 2 synchronizes for StandardUserDefaults necessary?

Tags: iphone, application-settings

I am changing app settings within my iPhone application.

Strangely, I have to do **2 synchronize commands** with `StandardUserDefaults` to make my changes to be reflected in the app settings.

Secondly, when I change my "preferred user language" within my iPhone application, I do have to start my app **twice** for the language change.

What's the reason for that?

Is there a way to dump the `StandardUserDefaults` and to see all the settings stored there?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What does it mean for the “changes to be reflected in the app settings?”

Comment: Im having the same problem, sometimes changes in NSUserDefaults just do not get saved even if I call synchronize, some strange caching going on

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to dump the StandardUserDefaults and to see all the settings stored there?

Yes, that is pretty easy to do.

The NSUserDefaults are stored in a plist file located in your app's sandboxed environment inside the Library folder.

For checking this on the simulator, have a look at

> ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/5.0/Applications/[hashed app
>   identifier]/Library/Preferences/[application bundle identifier].plist

Note that you will have to replace the values in brackets to find your specific app. Also note that this path works for the iOS5.0 environment - for others, you will have to replace the 5.0 with whatever system version you are working with.

Comment: Thanks for your immediate answer. I can find this plist-file, but I cannot open it, because it is a link, and the original file cannot be found. What I am supposed to do? Thanks Florian

Comment: It should not be a link. I suspect what you see is something like a link to `com.apple.PeoplePicker.plist` - but additionally you should see a proper file (not link/alias) containing your app-specific defaults.

Comment: Correct, but there is only com.apple.PeoplePicker.plist. There are no further entries

Comment: I had one more look into the preferences directory. Unfortunately, there is no plist file (except com.apple.PeoplePicker.plist, which is a link).